# Columnas cruzadas en DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe (que surge de unir varios .csv) donde tengo 2 columnas que tienen contenido cruzado entre ellas, alguna idea de como solucionarlo, gracias.

Ejemplo

```
inimputable1623['nacionalidad'].unique()
```

devuelve: array(['Argentina', nan, 'MASCULINO', 'Uruguay', 'Ucrania', 'Paraguay'],
dtype=object)

```
inimputable1623['sexo'].unique()
```

devuelve:array(['MASCULINO', nan, 'Argentina'], dtype=object)

Comment: Hola Lucas, ¿a qué te refieres con "contenido cruzado" exactamente? Considera agregar un [ejemplo mínimo reproducible](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de dataframe que muestre el problema así como la salida esperada para ese ejemplo.

Comment: ahi edite la pregunta. Gracias por la sugerencia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo corregi de la siguiente manera

```
# Función para corregir los valores cruzados
def corregir_valores_cruzados(row):
    if row['sexo'] in list_nac and row['nacionalidad'] not in list_nac:
        temp = row['sexo']
        row['sexo'] = row['nacionalidad']
        row['nacionalidad'] = temp
    return row

# Aplicar la función a cada fila del DataFrame
inimputable1623 = inimputable1623.apply(corregir_valores_cruzados, axis=1)
```